# When part of an object becomes the name for the whole

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe when a part becomes the name for the whole, particularly in a jargon sense?

For example, a door to door salesman at the end of the day might talk about how many "doors" he visited, rather than houses, or a pathology nurse might talk about "doing veins" rather seeing patients?

I read a definition along these lines years and years ago, but I've completely forgotten the word. If possible I'm trying to find this same word again.

Comment: Try searching "part for the whole": you should come up with [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy).

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche

Comment: I've got no idea how this could be a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: Well the linked question explains synecdoche & metonymy, so it (albeit indirectly and implicitly) answers yours @phill.

Comment: They're related, but clearly distinct questions.

Comment: *Pars pro toto* seems to be an established term in English, although it is three words.

Comment: if you use synecdoche to refer to metonymies, is this a synecdoche?

Comment: "Marking something as a duplicate does not necessarily mean that the accepted answer answers all variations of a question; nor even that the closed question is precisely the same as another — that would normally result in the questions being merged. It generally means that one of the answers provides enough information to answer the closed question, in much the same way as a reference book might provide examples which need to be adapted slightly to the problem in hand." (from: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5239/14073)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd say that would be a [***synecdoche***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche).

> A synecdoche (/sɪˈnɛkdəkiː/, si-nek-də-kee; from Greek συνεκδοχή, synekdoche, lit. "simultaneous understanding")[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) is a figure of speech in which a term for a part of something refers to the whole of something or vice versa

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche

Answer (score 3):

The more common word used is ***metonymy***.  The classic examples of that would be calling a car "wheels" or a police officer a "copper" (what their badges were made of), or military officers "brass" (their button material).

> me·ton·y·my məˈtänəmē/
>
> noun: metonymy; plural noun: metonymies
>
> the substitution of the name of an attribute or adjunct for that of the thing meant, for example *suit* for business executive, or *the track* for horse racing.